# Bind variable to enum variant during pattern matching

Tags: rust

How do I make this work?

```rust
enum A {
    A1(B)
}

enum B {
    B1 {
        num: u64,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::A1(B::B1 { num: 123 });
    match a {
        A::A1(b @ B::B1 { .. }) => {
            println!("{}", b.num); // <-- no field `num` on type `B`
        }
    }
}
```

That is, the goal is to bind the inner `B::B1` variant to a variable and then access the fields of that match. But the variant is gone, and the bound `b` variable is a meaningless, generic enum again.

I know I can access `B::B1`'s internal fields if I destructure all of them manually, but that is kinda inconvenient. Is there a way to just "remember" the inner enum variant somehow?

Comment: `Is there a way to just "remember" the inner enum variant somehow?` I really don't think there is. Not even the most basic example i could think of "remembers" this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0601d75860d56fcb2951d643572414c4

Comment: Use a struct inside the variant.

Comment: @Finomnis I meant something like `struct B1 { num: u64 } enum B { B1(B1) }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I see. Well, my answer agrees with your opinion ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `B::B1` is not a **type**. It's a **value**.

`b` itself is of type `B`, and `B` does not have a `.num` member.

To get the value out of an enum, you have to destructure it directly, like this:

```rust
enum A {
    A1(B),
}

enum B {
    B1 { num: u64 },
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::A1(B::B1 { num: 123 });
    match a {
        A::A1(B::B1 { num }) => {
            println!("{}", num);
        }
    }
}
```

```
123
```

---

The usecase you have here is not uncommon and is usually solved via nested structs, as can be seen in [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html):

```rust
enum A {
    A1(B),
}

struct B1 {
    num: u64,
}

enum B {
    B1(B1),
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::A1(B::B1(B1 { num: 123 }));
    match a {
        A::A1(B::B1(b)) => {
            println!("{}", b.num);
        }
    }
}
```

```
123
```